# Extracting values in a map

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

WE have a map Students { studentId : StudentData }.
StudentData is a POJO with student attributes .
The requirement is to get all students with attribute `isCurrent==true`.
If so,then extract the city attribute for the student.
This will used to increment the count of a studentpercity map `{ city : count }`

```
Students.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(x -> true == x.getValue().isCurrent())
                .forEach(x -> {
                      studentpercity(x.getValue().getCity(), (studentpercity.getOrDefault(x.getValue().getCity(), 0) + 1));
                      });
```

Th final output will be a map of city to count of 'current' students.
Is there a more efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: `However,this seems to involve multiple iterations of the map.` - why do you think it requires multiple iterations? I see a single iteration over the entries of the Map.

Comment: What exactly is the desired output? Just a number for a given city? Or maybe a `Map<String, Integer>` representing a cities and the corresponding amount of students? Or do you have such a `Map` and want do increment counters?

Comment: I don't think you need to filter your stream. You could just add an if statement inside the forEach loop so you "save" the filter iteration over the stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may do it like so,

```
Map<String, Long> studentPerCity = students.values().stream().filter(StudentData::isCurrent)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(StudentData::getCity, Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative could look like this:

```java
students.values().stream()
                .filter(StudenData::isCurrent)
                .map(StudenData::getCity)
                .forEach(city -> studentpercity(city, studentpercity.getOrDefault(city, 0) + 1));
```

However, regarding you comment about "iterations". In a single stream (like you example) every element is only iterated once. That means every operation in the stream will be applied once on every element and that only if not filtered out before.